# Setting up thunderbird with tiscalli (for newsgroup access)

Tags: thunderbird, newsreader, newsgroups

I have just downloaded thunderbird 3.0.2 and want to set it up to read newsgroups. My ISP is tiscalli.

I have entered the News server address, but I still cant download any newsgroups - has anyone managed to get this working?

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of your configuration windows.

Comment: Which country are you in and which configuration are you using at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

I had this setup working fine a few months back.  news.tiscali.co.uk is the nntp server and it ran ok, albeit slowly.  It's perhaps worth checking they haven't changed anything since they were bought out by Talk Talk.